# Understanding Results of Querying ContentWorkspace

Tags: apex, soql, content, libraries

How is access or readabiity of a ContentWorkspace (library) determined? The following query is returning different results for me:

`select id, name from ContentWorkspace`

When logged in as a System Admin, the above query seems to only return the libraries I am a member of.

When logged in as a Portal User, the query seems to return all libraries.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ContentWorkspace](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm#custom_portal_no_access_section) docs:

> ## Special Access Rules
>
> - Customer and Partner Portal users can only edit the library document object if they have a Salesforce CRM Content feature license.
> - Customer and Partner Portal users can query this object if they have
>     the “View Content in Portal” permission. **A user can query all public
>     libraries where they are members, regardless of library permissions.**

I suspect that if your portal users aren't explicitly gaining access to the ContentWorkspaces as members they are in a group that has access.

Comment: You're absolutely right! In my case, I just did not immediately see that their membership is given through public groups. Thank you!