# System admin unable to see all ContentWorkspace

Tags: libraries, contentworkspace

Let's say you have two users, each with `System Administrator` profile

- `Sysad1`
- `Sysad2`

Each user has `Salesforce CRM user` permission. The System Administrator profile includes

- `Manage Salesforce CRM Content` permission by default
- `Access Libraries` permission by default
- `Query All Files` added by Permission Set based on @identigral's suggestion

### Given

`Sysad2` creates a Library (`ContentWorkspace`) called `Library2`

- No explicit sharing given to `Sysad1` or any group `Sysad1` belongs to.

### When

the running user is `Sysad1`, none of these queries return `Library2`:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM ContentWorkspace
SELECT Id, name FROM ContentWorkspace Using Scope AllPrivate
SELECT Id, name FROM ContentWorkspace Using Scope Everything
```

---

**Really?** A profile with `View All Data` can't see a library (`ContentWorkspace`) created, but not shared, by some other sysad user?

- [Related (2013) question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/11802/2602)

What permission am I missing here?

Comment: This [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395050&type=1) talks about the same scenario but for querying of docs in a library. Based on this, it appears that `View All Data` isn't _all_ data, CMS has explicit additional perms. The [Content Workspace doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm) mentions `Access Libraries` perm, try that?

Comment: @identigral - `Access Libraries` was already enabled (I edited the OP); I added `Query All Files` via a PermissionSet. That had no effect on querying ContentWorkspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a call with SFDC Support:

- It is working as designed
- There is no Known Issue
- A suggested workaround to get all the unique `ContentDocument.ParentId` does not work - you will not get access to libraries the running user is not a member of, despite `View All Data`

A user with `View All Data`:

- If using Classic, they can see libraries they are not a member of. Taking the Id from the address bar and doing a SOQL query with that Id will not find the library. In LEX, you can't get this far.
- In Classic, although you can see the library, you can not see any files (even by name) within that library. In LEX, you can't even get this far.

I logged a documentation suggestion for the [ContentWorkspace object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm?q=contentworkspace).